# How can we compute resultant r-squared value from 2 r-squared values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, data-analysis

Is there an efficient way of combining 2 r-squared values?
Those 2 r-squared values are computed for 2 parts of same data set(I have to divide the data in to 2 parts, say 70% and 30%). I want to calculate the resultant r-squared value. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: This cannot be done. These 2 values are not comparable.

Comment: IMO, your best bet would be to save the residuals for both for all data points, then compute on the whole set rather than computing each individually

Comment: I divided a data set into 2 parts, (say 70% and 30%).  As the r-squared values are computed from the residuals of same data set, I need a way to combine those r- squared values.